# Learning Python and need some direction with paths

Tags: python, flask, import, python-3.9

stuck right now. Trying to make a website and have an ImportError I have no idea how to get around.

Files are organised as such
Main folder: website

Secondary folder1: static

Secondary folder2: templates - **init**.py , auth.py , views.py , models.py

main.py located in main folder

**Trying to import from **init**.py to main.py**

****init**.py**

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "NG2022"

    return app
```

**main.py**

```
from website import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

> ImportError: cannot import name 'create_app' from 'website' (unknown location)

Please help, I'm very confused :(

Comment: do you have a `__init__.py` file in every folder? And if you can show the folder structure with the `tree` command that would be nice

Answer (score 2):

You have to follow the guidelines of file names while separating your project in

```
> simply rename your init file __init__
```

further more  : when you're importing between your files in the project use the indexing method like

`from website.__init__ import create_app`

however you don't need to do that for the

```
>  __init__
```

file because it execute first automatically